# Reducing JSF Memory Footprint: Relationship between View State and Bean Scope

Tags: jsf, memory, richfaces, scalability

I am working on a RichFaces-based JSF application that has com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession and com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews parameters set to 1 but has most of the managed beans set to a "session" scope. If reducing the memory footprint is the prime objective (with no significant deterioration to the page rendering times as well), what would be a better option?

- Changing the scope to "request" so that the view state is not held for too long (unlike when the scope is set to "session").

I read somewhere that the scope of the beans could have a bearing on the size of the view (and "request" scoped beans may not necessarily be available for GC at the end of the request). I have seen a performance degradation in this case, straightaway though.

- Changing the scope to "application" since a number of pages are user-agnostic and don't really change based on the authenticated user. The application scope would result in a singleton and therefore, would the overall memory associated with a bean would be significantly lower as it is not tied to a user?

Also, would this result in the JSF View lingering around for a little too long? If yes, this would make it worse than how it is currently with the session scoped beans.

Last but not the least, there are multiple forms within a view. Could this play a role as well in increasing the memory footprint?

Comment: Why are you using a stateful component based MVC framework like JSF when you're apparently after an extremely small memory footprint?

Comment: Good question. I am inheriting code/architecture and am limited to the nature of architectural changes I could possibly make. I want to be able to make the best out of the existing architecture and have it scale.

Answer (score 0):

If the beans don't really change for different users and they are going to be needed most of the time set them to Application scope. That way only one instance of the object will be instantiated and all requests will use it.

For objects that are not shared by all users using Request scope should make them eligible for  garbage collection immediately instead of hanging around until the user's session expires.

That doesn't mean that the collector will run immediately but when collection is done they will be removed.